# TFS 2015 - unparented tasks not showing on backlog items

Tags: tfs-2015, backlog

I'm using TFS 2015, with Agile process template.

With the new TFS Update 1 you can now create new Items (Bugs/Tasks and more..) via the Home Dashboard and that's really nice and easy to explain to non-technical users like project managers.

I have added a new task, and it was automatically set it to Iteration 1.

Assuming my project manager will open Bugs and Tasks from the Home Dashboard, who said i'm going to resolve that on the Current Iteration?

So I have changed that task Iteration field to the *Team Project* (Meaning for me - not currently on any iteration, waiting to be set to some iteration in the future).

Then i go to my Backlog page and i noticed that my newly created task isn't showing on the Backlog.

As far as i read on the net you can't change the Backlog query.

So my question is:
How do i make my Unparented task be shown on the backlog?

And if i can't have it, can someone help me understand what is the best practice for this process?
Again, assuming my project manager, and it's employees will go to the home screen, clicking "New work item" and will just create the bug/task, add the description, change the iteration to *Team Project* and will assume i will see it and refer it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know if we create a User Story under iteration *Team Project*, then we can track it on backlogs. So we can treat Task and Bug in the same way by adding Task and Bug work item types to to backlogs too.

You'll need to export the following objects from your team project, update them, and import them:

- WIT you want to add to backlogs and boards
- Categories definition
- ProcessConfiguration

Detailed steps refer to MSND article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/customize/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards#wit-as-requirements

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does the default behavior of the Agile Template means that every new created task/bug should automatically get added to the Current iteration? Does it match the Agile Methodology? It just seems strange to me that this is the default and for the so common process like creating new task i have to, as team leader, find it in the current iteration, create matching user story on backlog and add link to the task to it. I just wonder how other projects handle this situation.

Comment: New created task/bug doesn't get added to the Current iteration, but added to the iteration that Set as team's backlog iteration (You can change it under Iteration tab on Administration page).